# Upload textarea contents as a file using Angular

Tags: angular, upload, textarea

I need to transform content from the textarea to the file.txt and upload it to the server (without downloading this file). Is there a way to do this Angular, or JS?

Comment: Why don't you try the text file creation in your sever side?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. In your server side, accept the content as a multipart file like this.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadFile(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            throws FileUploadFailedException, ContentTypeNotCorrectException {
}
```

In your front end the code would be as below. You need to call this service from your component.

```
upload(content: string, filename:string) {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}files`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Accept', 'application/json');
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', content, filename);
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData, {
    });
```